# Can't find local gem when installed with --install-dir

Tags: ruby, rubygems

So i have to gems that i created and they only exist locally.

When i install gem A like this:

```
gem install --install-dir my_install_dir a-0.0.0.gem
```

It works fine, also dependencies are installed.

But then i try to install gem B, which has a dependency on gem A the same way:

```
gem install --install-dir my_install_dir b-0.0.0.gem
```

Now i geht the following error:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'a' (~> 0.0) (required by 'b-0.0.0.gem' (>= 0)) in any repository
```

---

I tried setting the GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH to the install dir "my_install_dir", but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use --force as part of your gem command

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.